# cannot access samba shares

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

I'm new to linux, but I'm trying to learn. I hope someone can help me out here.

I just installed ubuntu-server and i'm trying to set up some smb shares, my problem is that samba spits an the error every time I try to connect, from either windows or linux. Both on windows and on my linux laptop I get the " unable to find network location " error. On the server I get the one below.

```
[2024/01/17 19:04:33.080528,  0] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:3448(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/main failed. Permission denied
```

The directory I'm sharing is inside a zfs pool ( the pool is mounted in /main ),  /main/media.
I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, I'm hoping someone could point out what is it.
UFW is disabled, and I don't have SELinux. Actually, there are no firewall on this server aside from ufw.

The /main folder has these permissions, and is inside the root directory. I just did a chmod 777 on everything out of frustration, I know..

```
drwxrwxrwx   3 root root          3 Jan 14 13:50 main
```

the /main/media folder has the following

```
drwxrwxrwx 4 shareuser root 4 Jan 17 13:13 media
```

my smb.conf conf.

```
[media]
path = /main/media
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
public = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 755
force user = enfinders
force group = enfinders
```

inside smb.conf the interface is the one I'm using

```
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 enp2s0
```

and just for good measure I set

```
;   bind interfaces only = no
```

edit: adding the result of testparm -s

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[media]
        create mask = 0644
        force group = enfinders
        force user = enfinders
        guest ok = Yes
        path = /main/media
        read only = No
```

net usershare doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is Samba running? Try `systemctl status smbd`.

Comment: You error message says `/var/lib/samba/usershares/main` is not accessible, there is nothing about `/main/media`.

Comment: Yeah samba is running, no errors as well :(

Comment: But that is the only message I have in the logs. There is nothing else. On the other machines it says simply " network location not found", and it writes the error above in the logs at the time I try to connect.

Comment: Please edit your original post and add the output of these two commands: `testparm -s`  `net usershare info --long`

Comment: Done, edited original post, but the net usershare command doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts for you to try and solve your issue, i make the mistake of every time i re install a linux distro, i install samba and copy my smb.conf over that was working perfectly.

What i always forget, is to create the samba user, command is

```
    sudo smbpasswd -a Usernamehere
```

for more info on the command [link to more details](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/adding-a-user-to-a-samba-smb-share/)!

The other thing i sometimes find is that shares will not show up on there own and need to be found manually by typing in the ip of the server into your file manager. Something along the lines of

smb://192.168.1.XXX or what ever the ip of your server is.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work . tried with sudo smbpasswd -a myusername, which let's me set up a password, but upon restarting samba it keeps giving me that error.